# chromedriver file not recognized by my PyPI installed package

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pypi, sys

I created a python package and published it in PyPI. The package code is based on chromedriver selenium. I added the chromedriver file in the PyPI package folder and mentioned the file path in the code :

```
driver_path= Path.cwd() / "chromedriver"
```

However when I install the package using pip install my-package. The code returns the classical error:

`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`

This can be solved only by manually downloading and adding the chromedriver to the package folder. Is there a better way to make the chromedriver automatically installed and configured when my PyPI package is installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. The trick is to import your python package in your own code and then get the package path:

```
import Path
try:
            import your_pypi_package
            package_path=str(your_pypi_package.__path__).split("'")[1]
            driver_path= Path(package_path) / "chromedriver"
except:
            driver_path= Path.cwd() / "chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=driver_path, options=options)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, you'll need to instruct your user how to install Chrome and the chromemdriver for their platform.